# Why won't my geometry node setup rotate instances to normal?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I think has something to do with instance at points, but I need your help. You see the instances have no rotation currently. The mesh that has the curve modifier has normals that change along the curve. Maybe the normal is not being honored because it's resulting from a modifier. Thanks all.
[image: 1]

[image]

[image]

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17U4XlAe2qKvea-HgW0axGr5L-aLFlgV-/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation

It's because you are using a *mesh to points*, and points don't have normals.

#### Solution

so capture the normals before you convert the mesh to points and use that captured normals for the *align Euler to vector* (set the capture attribute to *vector* and *face*).